# How to compare lists in pytest using assert statement (added double quotes)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

I am trying to compare results of two lists using assert statement to test the function using **pytest**. Whenever I try to compare using assert statement, my expected result is automatically converted to a string with double quotes. This is so far I have done:

```
# read data from xlsx file 

book = xlrd.open_workbook("nameEntityDataSet.xlsx")

first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) # get first worksheet

# take second element(index starts from 0) from first row

se1 = first_sheet.row_values(1)[1]

print "se1 ", se1 #returns me list:
# take third element(index 2) from first row 

se2 = first_sheet.row_values(1)[2]

expected_output = first_sheet.row_values(1)[3]

#expected output is printed as:  [['UAE', 'United'], ['UAE', 'Arab'], ['UAE', 'Emirates']]

current_output = [['UAE', 'United'], ['UAE', 'Arab'], ['UAE', 'Emirates']]

#When I do assert to compare both outputs
assert current_output == expected_output
```

Returns this error:

> assert [['UAE', 'United'], ['UAE', 'Arab'], ['UAE', 'Emirates']] == "[['UAE', 'United'], ['UAE', 'Arab'], ['UAE', 'Emirates']]"
>       test_wordAligner.py:15: AssertionError

I do not know why it adds double quotation marks on expected output. Due to this reason I am getting AssertionError. I have searched a lot but did not find any helpful answer in my case. Please note that I want solution in **pytest** not **unittest**

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like `expected_output` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `expected_output` is a string and your asserting against a list.

```
expected_output = first_sheet.row_values(1)[3]
```

That line returns a string. Since you accessing one particular item of the list returned by `row_values(1)`. In order, to help you debug, try to:

```
print(type(expected_output))
```

This will show you that `expected_output` is a string at the moment.

Now, in order to trasnform it to list, here is something you could try:

```
import ast #put this at the top of your file
expected_output = first_sheet.row_values(1)[3]
expected_output = ast.literal_eval(expected_output)
```

Then you can compare both values.